# JSF 2.0; escape="false" alternative to prevent XSS?

Tags: java, jsf, xss

In my jsf webapplication i'm using a messages.properties to output some text. This text could have html line breaks so format the outputtext.

That all works fine, if i set the escape="false" attribute to the outputtext.

The problem is, this attribute with value "false" doesn't prevent vor XSS (cross site scripting) so i remove this attribute and use default-value "true".

So, i dont want to split all text lines to seperate properties in my messages.properties like in this example:

```
mytext = This is my text<br />with line break and user value {0}...
```

after:

```
mytext1 = This is my text
mytext2 = with line break and user value {0}...
```

is there any way, other than escape="false" but that prevent from xss?

thanks!

Comment: You only have to care about XSS when displaying a user content, like comments. For your own text (from properties) just do not place malicious code in there :)

Comment: Okay, but if there is any user content in there? I updated my question :-)

Comment: I suppose these are only read-only components so how could anyone XSS them? I do not think that output text cares about values sent by the client. If I am wrong you can always extends the JSF component u r interested in and prevent XSS. If u r using Tomcat 7.0 it provides XSS prevention out of the box

Comment: What about validating user values? e.g. not allowing user to choose his name as `<script type="text/javascript" .....`

Comment: Osw you said it your self[validate]..."Create a validator". If you want a more centralized approach create a filter to sanitize the HTTP request parameter values

Comment: Do not do it during request processing. This is not the normal approach and you'll risk double-escaping. Do it during response processing only. Jorn has already posted an answer how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be possible to just escape the user supplied parameter using the [standard jstl functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/fn/tld-summary.html) in the `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions` namespace:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.myMessage}" escape="false">
    <f:param value="#{fn:escapeXml(param)}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Answer (score 2):

XSS can't happen if you're outputting some HTML from a *safe* source which is not input or editable by the user. You can safely use `escape="false"` in this case.

Comment: In some outputtext i've got some user content... i updated my question