# How to prevent XSS attack when h:outputFormat is used with escape=false?

Tags: xss, jsf-1.2

Am using JSF 1.2. I want to display a message to User which reads like this

"Please [click here](http://google.com/) to login with your new password."

Code in my xhtml page,

`<h:outputFormat value="#{msg.resetBackToLogin}" escape="false"></h:outputFormat>`

And below is the code from my Property file.

Please `<a href="http://myDomain/">` click here `</a>` to login with your new password.

Since, it contains special characters, am using `h:outputFormat` with `escape=false`. I felt, using `h:commandLink` and calling a bean method and redirecting there will simply add overhead.

As am using `h:outputFormat` with `escape=false`, this will lead to XSS attack. How can I prevent this if am sticking to `h:outputFormat`?

Comment: How does this lead to XSS? You are displaying a trusted string containing a trusted html fragment. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Erlend Please check these links [Link1](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CrossSiteScripting). This talks in specific to Seam. This [Link2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/securing-your-jsf-pages) talks in general. And this [Link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972870/jsf-2-0-escape-false-alternative-to-prevent-xss) talks about "Safe source" and non-editable text which I didn't exactly understood what Safe source was meant to be. So, am under the impression that my above code could lead to XSS. Hope am clear.