# Prevent XSS Reflection in JSF <f:param>

Tags: java, jsf, parameters, xss, cross-site

I am supporting a legacy application that uses JSF (and JSP). I am doing my best to prevent XSS by adding validators and escapes to the code as necessary. I'm new to JSF.

Code Example (in xhtml):

```
<h:form id="someForm">
<f:param name="someProperty" value="#{someBean.someProperty}"/>
</h:form>
```

My Issue
Our security scanner is saying this is vulnerable to XSS Reflection. I'd like to add an escape to the property value.

My Research:
I've read JSF typically automatically escapes everything in . It has a parameter you must set to fales in order to disable this. However it seems  does not have this functionality. I found a suggested code snippet that might work:

```
<f:param name="someProperty" value="#{fn:escapeXml(someBean.someProperty)}"/>
```

However when I use *fn:escapeXml* the page fails to load. How is this typically solved?

*Note, this is a critical legacy app. Least evasive action is desired.*

Aforementioned article:
[JSF 2.0; escape="false" alternative to prevent XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972870/jsf-2-0-escape-false-alternative-to-prevent-xss)

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Browser error is not useful:
Failed to open http://localhost:8080/someFile.jsf

I was able to get this out of the console in debug mode:
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Function 'fn:escapeXml' not found

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing.
Turns out one for my xhtml files was missing the required import:
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"

I added it in and it appears to work now!